# What is ram bank locator

Tags: linux, memory, hardware-failure, gpu, cups

I have two same rams installed in two different computers, when I do `dmidecode --type memory` on the two,  I have found the two RAMs have some different values, I am wondering why should be the case?

#### on System A:

```
Handle 0x0048, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0044
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 16384 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM2
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MHz
    Manufacturer: Corsair
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMK32GX4M2B3000C15  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

#### on System B:

```
Handle 0x0063, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0058
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 72 bits
    Size: 16384 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_D1
    Bank Locator: NODE 1
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MHz
    Manufacturer: Corsair
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: DIMM_D1_AssetTag
    Part Number: CMK32GX4M2B3000C15 
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 2666 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
```

Typically on the `Bank Locator` value in which A is `BANK 3` and B is `NODE 1`. What does those values mean? And does these different locators affects gpu-cpu data transfer? System B actually is facing this problem, [referring to my another question.](https://superuser.com/questions/1207119/two-systems-with-identical-gpus-have-very-different-performances-when-running-t)

#### Update systems info

System A: [Asus Z170-P](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z170-P/), [i7 6700T](http://ark.intel.com/products/88200/Intel-Core-i7-6700T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz), 32GB Ram, GTX 1080.

System B: [Asus X99 E-WS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/X99E_WS/), [i7 5930K](http://ark.intel.com/products/82931/Intel-Core-i7-5930K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz), 64G Ram, GTX 1080. (Problem one)

My rams are Corsair DDR4 3000MHz CMK32GBX4M2B3000C15

Comment: Could you actually provide details about the systems? That would probably make it way easier. As for what they mean ... they probably refer to the slot of the module(s). That information might be available in the other question but having it here would make it a "more complete" question.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Sure, I have updated my systems specs:)

Comment: Depending on what you do the i7 5930K (according to the ARK pages) has almost double the memory bandwidth. As for the Bank indicator it's probably motherboard dependent. One of the boards has only 4 slots and the other 8. The CPU only supports 4 channels so for 8 slots they might have "combined" two slots into one channel. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Yes, the docs of i7 5930k says it supports only 64G memory, but I did actually successfully ran with 128G which is quite strange. How can I debug or confirm the "combinning slots" action may cause a slow gpu-cup data transfer? Maybe I need to open another post to ask.

Comment: The only option I can think of is to put the CPU on another board that has a "standard" setup. That way you'd know whenever it's the CPU or the CPU to Memory connection. An other option might be to contact the vendor and ask for details but it's probably hard to get that kind of information.

Comment: Sadly, I only have this one motherboard support i7 5930k, so I can't do a cpu swapping check. Yes, I will try to get more information from my vendor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bank Locator: BANK 3** - means a memory module on a specific slot (3).

**Bank Locator: NODE 1** - can be a bank or a cluster of banks (like dual channel)

A node can have more bandwidth than a single RAM module on a bank.

The node concept (which divided up into a number of blocks called zones like DMA zone, Normal zone, HighMem Zone) helps Linux When allocating a page, where it uses a node-local allocation policy to allocate memory from the node closest to the running CPU. As processes tend to run on the same CPU, it is way more likely the memory from the current node will be used. Nodes are initialized by the kernel's  `init_bootmem_core()` function.

Additional note: In NUMA architectures, Node refers to the CPU+Memory combination.

Comment: Thats clear things up! By the way, can I possibly manually set the Bank locator from `node` to `bank` in bios? Since I believe this type of locator is causing a serious page fault problem when do gpu-cup data transfer.

Comment: If you have in BIOS an option called 'node interleaving' or 'memory interleaving', switching it should do. I think there's a new name for the equivalent too, but I'm note sure what it is. Normally, in single channel configurations, it should show as bank more often than as node.